# problems with translating a p5js sketch into processing

Tags: javascript, java, processing

I translate a p5js scetch to processing because I want to generate a mov file. The scetch is based on a tutorial from daniel shiffman on kadenze but I´ve got a problem now with a boolean output. How can I code this piece of p5js code in processing?

```
function draw() {
  for( var i = 0; i < particles.length; i++) {
    if(particles[i].isDead()) {
     //code
    }
  }
}

function Particles() {
  this.isDead = function() {
    var distance = p5.Vector.sub(attractor.pos, this.pos);
    var d = distance.mag();

    if(d < 5) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

First I tried it with void, but void hasn´t got an output. Then I tried something like this with boolean but it also doesn´t work.

```
void setup() {
  //code
}

void draw () {
  for (int i = 0; i < particles.length; i++) {
    if(particles[i].isDead()) {
      //code
    }
  }
}

Class Particle {
  Particle() {
    //code
  }

  boolean isDead() {
    PVector distance = PVector.sub(a.location, location);
    float d = distance.mag();

    if(d < 5) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

It will be great if somebody can help me.

regards mattias

Comment: Can you please provide a [mcve]? Right now you're missing the declaration of `particles` as well as `a` and `location`.

Answer (score 1):

The first problem is that you aren't ever actually doing anything if `isDead()` returns `true`. You need to actually put code inside that `if` statement, or maybe move that `if` statement to somewhere that makes logical sense.

For example, you could modify your `display()` function inside your `Mover` class to draw in green when the `Mover` is dead:

```
  void display() {
    if (isDead()) {
      fill(0, 255, 0);
    } else {
      fill(255, 0, 0);
    }
    stroke(0);
    strokeWeight(2);

    ellipse(location.x, location.y, 10, 10);
  }
```

That's just an example, and what you actually do depends on what you want to happen when a `Mover` is dead.

But even if you make that change, you'll notice that a `Mover` only dies when it reaches the middle of the gray circle. That's because of this `if` statement inside your `isDead()` function:

```
PVector distance = PVector.sub(a.location, location);
float d = distance.mag();
if (d < 5) {
  return true;
} else {
  return false;
}
```

You're measuring the distance between the center of the gray circle and the center of each little red circle. But you're only returning `true` if the `d < 5`. The problem with that is the gray circle has a diameter of 50, so if you want the little red circles to die when they enter the gray circle, you have to factor that diameter into your calculations. Try using `if(d < 30)` instead. I got 30 by dividing the diameter `50` by `2` and then adding `5` for the small circle size. You might have to play with it to get the effect you're looking for.

By the way, you might be interested in the `dist()` function, which returns the distance between two points. More info can be found in [the reference](https://processing.org/reference/dist_.html).